# How to embed Google calendar inside my website and still be able to add tasks to it?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

For instance `<div id=calcontent class=eui-t>...</div>` on website: https://www.google.com/calendar/render contains entire Google calendar. I want users of my ASP .NET MVC application be able to use it inside my website.

I would like to make it part of my view, embed it inside it.

**Question:** How to embed on my site contents of div tag: `<div id=calcontent class=eui=t></div>` from website www.google.com/calendar in the razor view?  I would like to make this calendar responsive on my site so I can still add task to this calendar.

Thanks to the suggestions in comments I could embed calendar inside my site but I can't add any tasks to it.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=r%40mobenti.com&ctz=UTC" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I have tried these to render whole calendar inside my site but I get blank 800x600 elemnts with nothing inside their `<body></body>`:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/?src=r%40mobenti.com&ctz=UTC" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=r@mobenti.com" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Use an iframe perhaps? Depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: May be issues about using an iframe as it's https?

Comment: @DavidG I try to render `<div id=calcontent class=eui=t></div>` from google calendar website inside my Razor view so user can see at the same time data showed on my site and inside google calendar(there will be no need to switch tabs in the browser).

Comment: I'd start with this https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en

Comment: @mitomed How to specify which <div> should be rendered inside iframe. Could you show it how to specify that I want only content of `<div id=calcontent class=eui=t></div>` to be rendered on my site? That might be answer. Thank you for sugestion.

Comment: @mitomed Iframe helped(please look at my edit) but I can't add any taks to it, can it be fixed?

Comment: @DavidG I rephrased entire OP could you please have a look? Thakn you.